# Compare and sync two (huge) directories - consider only filenames

Tags: linux, bash, synchronization, rsync

I want to do a one-way sync in Linux between two directories. One contains files and the other one contains *processed* files but has the same directory structure and the same filenames but some files might be missing.

Right now I am doing:

```
cd $SOURCE
find * -type f | while read fname; do
    if [ ! -e "$TARGET$fname" ]
    then
        # process the file and copy it to the target. Create directories if needed.
    fi
done
```

which works, but is painfully slow.
**Is there a better way to do this?**

There are rughly 50.000.000 files, spread among directories and sub-directories. Each directory does not contain more than 255 files/subdirs.

I looked at

- `rsync`: seems like it always does size or timestamp comparison. This will result on every file being flagged as different since the processing takes some time and changes the file contents.
- `diff -qr`: could not figure out how to make it ignore file-sizes and content

### Edit

Valid assumptions:

- comparisons are being made solely on directory/file names
- we don't care about file metadata and/or attributes (eg, size, owner, permissions, date/time last modified, etc)
- we don't care about files that may reside in the target directory but without a matching file in the source directory. This is only partially true, but deletions from the source are rare and happen in bulk, so I will do a special case for that.

Comment: fwiw, you could use `comm -13 "${srcfiles}" "${tgtfiles}"` to get a list of `${TARGET}`-only files for the bulk deletion process; alternatively, replace the `comm` calls with a single `diff` and use a condition to determine if the result is `${SOURCE}`-only or `${TARGET}`-only; personally, I find the `comm` output a bit easier to work with, ymmv ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- comparisons are being made solely on directory/file names
- we don't care about file metadata and/or attributes (eg, size, owner, permissions, date/time last modified, etc)
- we don't care about files that may reside in the target directory but without a matching file in the source directory

I don't see a way around comparing 2x lists of ~50 million entries but we can try to eliminate the entry-by-entry approach of a `bash` looping solution ...

One idea:

```
# obtain sorted list of all $SOURCE files

srcfiles=$(mktemp)
cd "${SOURCE}"
find * -type f | sort > "${srcfiles}"

# obtain sorted list of all $TARGET files

tgtfiles=$(mktemp)
cd "${TARGET}"
find * -type f | sort > "${tgtfiles}"

# 'comm -23' => extract list of items that only exist in the first file - ${srcfiles}

missingfiles=$(mktemp)
comm -23 "${srcfiles}" "${tgtfiles}" > "${missingfiles}"

# process list of ${SOURCE}-only files

while read -r missingfile
do
    process_and_copy "${missingfile}"
done < "${missingsfiles}"

'rm' -rf "${srcfiles}" "${tgtfiles}" "${missingfiles}"
```

---

This solution is (still) serial in nature so if there are a 'lot' of missing files the overall time to process said missing files could be appreciable.

With enough system resources (cpu, memory, disk throughput) a 'faster' solution would look at methods of parallelizing the work, eg:

- running parallel `find/sort/comm/process` threads on different `$SOURCE/$TARGET` subdirectories (may work well if the number of missing files is evenly distributed across the different subdirectories) or ...
- stick with the serial `find/sort/comm` but `split` `${missingfiles}` into chunks and then spawn separate OS processes to `process_and_copy` the different chunks

Comment: Your assumptions are spot-on. `comm` is new to mee. I think your solution might work well.

Comment: I wouldn't store the filemames in temporary files... Use process substitution instead. `comm -23 <(find ...) <(find ...)`

Comment: @Shawn worst case scenario: 2x 50 mil filenames, say an average of 50 characters per dir/file ... 5GB ... could be problematic on smaller (memory) systems, no?  and yes, would need to make sure FS where the 2x files end up has 5GB of space, but disk is still relatively cheap(er) than memory

Comment: sort uses temporary files for large data sets already, so I suspect using ones for the results will likely end up actually using more disk space.

Comment: first of all, thank you. It works. @markp-fuso assumptions about file sizes are quite good. I tested it on 1/5th of the data and the tmp file for the source is 1.1 GiB. While this would fit into RAM, i prefer a file since each `find` step takes roughly 20 minutes. Now that finding the files is no longer the bottleneck I need to optimize the processing.

Comment: @masgo yeah, for large chunks of intermediate data there's nothing like a bit of persistency especially if you're looking to do some testing on those intermediate results; fwiw, if you run into issues with optimizing the process I'd recommend starting a new question (as opposed to adding onto this Q&A)

Comment: also consider reviewing the man pages for `sort` as their are some options for memory/cpu allocations that may assist with speeding up the sorts

Comment: @markp-fuso this is now fast enough. Creating the list of missing files takes less than an hour. For processing, I can now just split up the missingfiles-list and start multiple tasks in parallel, such that it fully utilizes the server. The actual processing algorithm is done by someone else. They can now look into it. Luckily, each file can be processed independently. So either they optimize it, or throw more CPU power (=money) at it. ... btw. there is a " missing in the line `comm -23 "${srcfiles}" ${tgtfiles}" > "${missingfiles}"`  - I can not edit it because "edits need to be 6 chars"